# Change project wide variables

Tags: django, django-views

I have built a web application using Django that, among other things, can send emails to clients. When I'm in development mode, I don't want any my testing emails to actually go to the clients. Instead I want to re-route the email to me.

Currently, when developing on my dev server (which has a clone of all the code via git) I just comment out the lines that have the client's email address, and add my email address. This seems like a very poor method of handling this situation. I've already been burned by it (sending out 1,700 emails to all the clients and, oh look, they're **ALL** *coming to my email address*... brutal)

I was thinking of implementing a project wide variable called `DEV` that lives in `settings.py`. Then, I'd build a context processor which simply returns this variable's value. That way, in all my views, I could simply call the context processor and, if `DEV` is true, I could set the `email-to` value to be my email address. Otherwise, the `email-to` address would be a client email. Finally, I could set `git` to ignore my `settings.py` file so that the dev server `DEV` variable would always be `True` and the production server `DEV` variable would always be `False`.

Problem solved? Is this a good approach? Any better ways of tackling this?

---

**EDIT**

It seems I'm misunderstanding the fact that context processors are used in a template, not in a view. I suppose my question needs to actually be, how do I handle this so that I can check this variable from any view?

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want to do apart from the context processor. It has nothing to do with your views.

What I would do is the following decorator:

```
def email(function=None):
    def _decorator(view_function):
        def _view(request, *args, **kwargs):
            if settings.DEV:
                settings.EMAIL_TO = 'mymail@host.com'
            return view_function(request, *args, **kwargs)
        _view.__name__ = view_function.__name__
        _view.__dict__ = view_function.__dict__
        _view.__doc__ = view_function.__doc__

        return _view

    if function:
        return _decorator(function)
    return _decorator
```

This way you can do

```
@email
def my_view(request, args):
    #send your emails here
    return HttpResponse("mail sent")
```

I think that explicit decorators is far better than using Middlewares (which you confused with a ContextProcessor).

Hope it helps!